# Can someone help me with this class?

Tags: c++, class, std

**To make sure everyone understand my question, I will post the whole problem here.**

> In the Programming Example Election Results, the object candidateList
>   of the type orderedArrayListType is declared to process the voting
>   data. The operations of inserting a candidate’s data and updating and
>   retrieving the votes were somewhat complicated. To update the
>   candidate’s votes, we copied each candidate’s data from candidateList
>   into a temporary object of the type candidateType, updated the
>   temporary object, and then replaced the candidate’s data with the
>   temporary object. This is because the data member’s list is a
>   protected member of candidateList, and each component of list is a
>   private data member.
>
> In this lab, you are to modify the Programming Example Election
>   Results to simplify the accessing of a candidate’s data as follows:
>
> Derive a class candidateListType from the class orderedArrayListType.

```
 class candidateListType: public orderedArrayListType<candidateType> {

 public:

 candidateListType(); //default constructor candidateListType(int
 size); //constructor

 void processVotes(string fName, string lName, int region, int votes);
 //Function to update the number of votes for a //particular candidate
 for a particular region. //Postcondition: The name of the candidate,
 the region, //and the number of votes are passed as parameters.

 void addVotes(); //Function to find the total number of votes received
 by //each candidate.

 void printResult() const; //Function to output the voting data. };
```

> Because the class candidateListType is derived from the class
>   orderedArrayListType, and list is a protected data member of the class
>   orderedArrayListType (inherited from the class arrayListType), list
>   can be directly accessed by a member of the class candidateListType.
>
> Write the definitions of the member functions of the class
>   candidateListType. Rewrite and run your program using the class
>   candidateListType.

**That is the whole problem. After some help, I already done with the candidateListType class:**

```
candidateListType:
class candidateListType: public orderedArrayListType
{
public:
candidateListType(); //default constructor
candidateListType(int size); //constructor
void processVotes(string fName, string lName, int region, int votes);
//Function to update the number of votes for a
//particular candidate for a particular region.
//Postcondition: The name of the candidate, the region,
//and the number of votes are passed as parameters.
void addVotes();
//Function to find the total number of votes received by
//each candidate.
void printResult() const;
//Function to output the voting data.
orderedArrayListType<candidateType>& cList;
std::orderedArrayListType<candidateType>::iterator it;

//default constructor
candidateListType :: candidateListType(){
cList = new orderedArrayListType<candidateType>(100);
}

//constructor
candidateListType :: candidateListType(int size){
cList = new orderedArrayListType<candidateType>(size);
}

//processing votes...storing objects
candidateListType :: void processVotes(string fName, string lName, int region, int votes){
candidateType temp;
temp.setName(fName,lName);
temp.setVotes(region,votes);
it = orderedArrayListType.end();
orderedArrayListType.insert(it,temp);
}
//priting total votes data
candidateListType :: void addVotes(){
for (it=orderedArrayListType.begin(); it!=orderedArrayListType.end(); ++it){
cout<<*it.printData();
}
}

//printing results

candidateListType :: void printResult(){
candidateListType temp;
int largestVotes = 0;
int sumVotes = 0;
int winLoc = 0;
int NO_OF_CANDIDATES = orderedArrayListType.end();
for (int i = 0; i < NO_OF_CANDIDATES; i++)
{
orderedArrayListType.retrieveAt(i,temp);
temp.printData();

sumVotes += temp.getTotalVotes();

if (largestVotes < temp.getTotalVotes())
{
largestVotes = temp.getTotalVotes();
winLoc = i;
}
}

orderedArrayListType.retrieveAt(winLoc,temp);
cout << endl << endl << "Winner: ";

string firstN;
string lastN;

cout << temp.getFirstName() << " " << temp.getLastName();
cout << ", Votes Received: " << temp.getTotalVotes() << endl << endl;
cout << "Total votes polled: " << sumVotes << endl;
}

};
```

But I still have problem with my main driver. I tried to put candidateListType to my main driver but I keep getting error.
Those errors are:

> 1>c:\users\cal11.cpp(24): error C2039: 'orderedArrayListType' : is not
>   a member of 'std'
>   1>c:\users\cal11\cal11.cpp(24): error C2059: syntax error
>   : '<'

This is my main driver:

> http://www.mediafire.com/download/rcu864f0p1v3kbh/Main+Driver.zip

Can you guys please help me with this?
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Fair info, nobody is going to bother downloading a file. Also note, your code is not readable without indentations.

Comment: How is `orderedArrayListType` defined? Whatever way it is defined, it is definitely not present in the `std` namespace. Hence the error.

Comment: Take a closer look at line 24 of the cal11.cpp source file.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::orderedArrayListType<candidateType>::iterator it;
```

Your custom code is not part of the standard namespace (or at least it shouldn't be) so remove the namespace prefix to read

```
orderedArrayListType<candidateType>::iterator it;
```

or if you have a custom namespace,

```
your_namespace_here::orderedArrayListType<candidateType>::iterator it;
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help, but after I deleted "std::", it still has errors.